# how can I get alert by success and fail

Tags: php, ajax

I have problem: how could I display alert with this situation?
This alert shows the same alert when it does pass or not pass data to database.

I tried success and error method, but still didn't get anything.

ajax.php:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#addDocumentForm').on('submit', function(e){  
  $('#select_image').change(function(){
       $('#addDocumentForm').submit();  
  });  

       e.preventDefault();  
       $.ajax({  
            url :"main.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:new FormData(this),  
            contentType:false,  
            processData:false,  
            success:function(data){

            location.reload(true);

            }
       })  
  });
```

main.php:

```
 if (!in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions)) {
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('asd');</script>";

    }else if (in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions)) {

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into document values('',?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$filename);
    $stmt->execute();
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('asd');</script>";
```

I put alert like this in main.php, but not working, only show alert in ajax.php.
I want to get alert also when data fail insert to database such as "file should be image", or "successfully added" when data insert successfully.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: i just made short but i just need alert

Comment: it's works and it insert to database i just need alert by fail and success

Comment: Of course it works, you might as well post minified code. On stackoverflow it is necessary to have proper code indentation for better readability and good practice in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in a different file, echoing a script does not affect the other file that the AJAX request was sent from. However, you can use the `data` parameter provided by AJAX's success function and append the script that you received to the body:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "main.php",  
    method: "POST",  
    data: new FormData(this),  
    contentType: false,  
    processData: false,  
    success: function(data){
        // append script to the body
        $('body').append(data);
    }
});
```

**You can also echo the string that you want to alert in** `main.php` **and use** `alert(data)` **directly from the success callback instead,** and I really suggest you do, but in the end it is your choice.

### EDIT (solution for the latter)

#### main.php

```
if (!in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions)) {
   echo "asd";
// etc ...
```

#### ajax.php

```
{
    success: function(data) {
        // alerts echoed content if any
        if(data) alert(data); 
    }
}
```